# Module rpaf_module is already loaded apache issue

Tags: apache, centos

I have problem on my CentOs 6 64bit VPS.
I have tried to install apachebooster 1.9 package which include nginx and varnish.
The vps worked perfectly but once I install the package, I can't get access to my websites and when I try to restart httpd service I receive this message :

> module rpaf_module is already loaded, skipping.

When i uninstall apachebooster the vps work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that the ability to access the site has anything to do with module warning.  However, as it is asked in the question, I will tell you how to resolve that warning message.

The issue is that you are loading that module twice.  Chances are you have multiple lines that look something like this:
LoadModule rpaf_module modules/mod_rpaf-2.0.so

It will likely either in httpd.conf or in a separate include file.

So edit the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (or wherever it is on your server) and look for rpaf.  If you see that line multiple times delete all but one.

If you see a line like:

```
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/rpaf.conf"
```

Then THAT's the file you need to edit.

Sometimes that file will have its whole contents repeated.  In my case, it was repeated two extra times and the file looked like this:

```
LoadModule rpaf_module modules/mod_rpaf-2.0.so
#Mod_rpaf settings
RPAFenable On
RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1 [..]
RPAFsethostname On
RPAFheader X-Real-IP
LoadModule rpaf_module modules/mod_rpaf-2.0.so
#Mod_rpaf settings
RPAFenable On
RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1 [..]
RPAFsethostname On
RPAFheader X-Real-IP
LoadModule rpaf_module modules/mod_rpaf-2.0.so
#Mod_rpaf settings
RPAFenable On
RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1 [..]
RPAFsethostname On
RPAFheader X-Real-IP
```

So I got the warning twice.  In this case all you need to do is delete everything from the second

```
LoadModule rpaf_module
```

line and on till the end.  Save and restart Apache.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure I solved this issue even though I haven't figure out how to get rpaf to work as it was working before.

After an update this directory was created /usr/local/etc/apache24/modules.d. If you run a cat on README_modules.d you will realize that these files are being loaded by default. Here you will find a file that starts with a number [1-9999] has a name '[a-z][A-Z]' and ends in '.conf' 200_mod_rpaf.conf the first line in this file is: "LoadModule rpaf_module    libexec/apache24/mod_rpaf.so" and there lies your problem. I'd comment out the instance of 'LoadModule'on the httpd.conf as this new configuration scheme seems to scale.